# Where to open system command in centos5.5?

Tags: linux, centos

I install Vmware in winxp sp3, then install centos 5.5-i386 release 2 in Vmware. For I am a newbie in linux, I want to type some command like `yum install ...`, but where to open system command? I searched the menu `applications` `places` `system` on the top of the desktop, but I am not sure which one is. Is there anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `terminal`, `console` or something with `term` or `console` in the name. It depends what GUI/shell and what applications you installed.

Answer (score 0):

`Applications` | `System Tools` | `Terminal`